# sed - How do I match this pattern?

Tags: sed

I'm using sed and I am having trouble finding out how to remove some of the first line of text from each block. Here is my original data:

```
  "s220823vaps2512":   {
"hostname": "s220823vaps2512",
"description": data",
"type": "Virtual",
"os": "data",
"idc": "data",
"environment": "data",
"deviceclass": "data",
"cores": "data",
"memory": "data",
"frontnet": "data",
"ipset":     {
  "backnet": "data",
  "storagenet": "data",
  "metroclusternet": "data"
},
"roles": "data",
"mounts": "data"
  },
   "s220823vaps2513":   {
"hostname": "s220823vaps2513",
"description": "data",
"type": "Virtual",
"os": "data",
"idc": "data",
"environment": "data",
"deviceclass": "data",
"cores": "data",
"memory": "data",
"frontnet": "data",
"ipset":     {
  "backnet": "data",
  "storagenet": "data",
  "metroclusternet": "data"
},
```

I want to use sed to successfully remove everything up until the `{` on the first line of each block leaving me with a data format similar to

```
{
 "hostname": "data",
  "etc": "etc",
},
{
 "hostname": "data",
  "etc": "etc",
},
```

Comment: Looks like JSON. Is it? If so, use a JSON parser. It's much much better that way.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is predicated on the above looking rather a lot like JSON, so I've therefore assumed it probably *is* `JSON`. But it's incomplete in your sample, which I have also assumed is a typo. If this isn't the case... well, you already have `sed` answers.

Please - don't use a regex to parse `JSON`. It's nasty. regex is bad at recursive tagged data types like `JSON`/`XML`. It's at best a dirty hack which creates brittle code in future.

Similarly - `JSON` is important that it be complete - I've had to guess how your full `JSON` looks.

Assuming `JSON` like this (used http://jsonlint.com/ to tidy up the elements)

```
{
    "s220823vaps2512": {
        "hostname": "s220823vaps2512",
        "description": "data",
        "type": "Virtual",
        "os": "data",
        "idc": "data",
        "environment": "data",
        "deviceclass": "data",
        "cores": "data",
        "memory": "data",
        "frontnet": "data",
        "ipset": {
            "backnet": "data",
            "storagenet": "data",
            "metroclusternet": "data"
        },
        "roles": "data",
        "mounts": "data"
    },
    "s220823vaps2513": {
        "hostname": "s220823vaps2513",
        "description": "data",
        "type": "Virtual",
        "os": "data",
        "idc": "data",
        "environment": "data",
        "deviceclass": "data",
        "cores": "data",
        "memory": "data",
        "frontnet": "data",
        "ipset": {
            "backnet": "data",
            "storagenet": "data",
            "metroclusternet": "data"
        }
    }
}
```

Then the way to just get the bits you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $input = ### as above, snipped for brevity. 

#decode/validated
my $json = decode_json ( $input );
#create new JSON array of elements. 
my $new_json = [map { $json -> {$_} } keys %$json];
#print it out. 
print to_json ( $new_json, { pretty => 1, canonical => 1 } );
```

And in this way, you create valid JSON output as well as handling cases where e.g. key ordering is different (which is entirely valid in JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Simple with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^{]*{/{/' file
```

- Just searches for lines starting with characters which are not `{` (`^[^{]`), zero or more times `*` followed by a `{`.
- This all is replaced by a single `{`.

**Edit**: If you want to exclude some patterns from being replace (for example the `"ipset":` line) use this:

```
sed '/"ipset":/n;s/^[^{]*{/{/' file
```

- If the line starts with `"ipset":`, continue with the next line `n`.

Comment: Will this not effect the ipset data?

Comment: Yes it does, if you don't want that, you need something to identify the other lines: is there a similarity in that names: `s220823vaps2513`? `s-digit-vaps-digit` or so?

Comment: Yes the names are similar in each line, probably around 10 variants though

Comment: Additionally can we use sed to *ignore* the ipset line as this is the only line that it would effect?

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer.

Comment: This doesn't ignore ipset

Comment: Try again now, maybe your line starts with a space/tab instead of `"ipset"...`

Comment: see, I'm afraid this is just one very good example why parsing JSON with regex is a headache.

Comment: @Sobrique That correct, use the right tool (would be a json parser). But the above is not valid json. The end tag is missing.

Comment: Yeah, it's missing a quote too. There's three possiblities there though - either it isn't JSON, or it was JSON and it's already been hacked, or it's a typo. I'd tend to assume the latter case, because doing something _very similar_ to JSON, but that _isn't quite_ is even more evil than using regex to parse it!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, at least on the sample of data you provided:

```
sed -'s/^ .*{/{/' file
```

It transforms the first line of each block `"name" {` (note the leading space) to just `{`